# Java FX Pie Chart - Change order of data

Tags: java, javafx

I implemented a small chart with a button to rotate the slice inside the chart, in order to do this, I implemented the following steps:

- Copy the actual data of the chart into a new ObservableList "ActualData"
- Create a new ObservableList "NewList" empty
- Add to NewList  the last value of ActualData, and then add the remaing values ( ind: 0,1,2,3 )
- Clear the data of the chart
- Enter using a loop all the data of the new list "NewList"

My questions are:

- Is there a better way to implement such action?
- Is a way to delete the ugly spaces between each slice?

Thanks

```
package application;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
       public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

           PieChart pieChart = new PieChart();
           int counter = 0;



           EnterValues(pieChart);

           pieChart.setLegendVisible(false);
           pieChart.setClockwise(true);
           pieChart.setStartAngle(90);

           StackPane.setAlignment(pieChart, Pos.TOP_CENTER);

           Button button = new Button("Change Values");

           StackPane.setAlignment(button, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);

           StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
           stackPane.setPrefSize(500, 500);
           stackPane.getChildren().add(pieChart);
           stackPane.getChildren().add(button);
           Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);


           primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
           primaryStage.setMinHeight(500);
           primaryStage.setMinWidth(500);
           primaryStage.setScene(scene);       
           primaryStage.show();


           button.setOnAction((EventHandler<ActionEvent>) new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {


                      // GET DATA FROM CURRENT LIST
                       ObservableList<Data> ActualData = pieChart.getData();
                      // CREATE NEW  EMPTY LIST
                       ObservableList<Data> NewList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();;

                      // ADD ITEMS TO NEW LIST ( LAST BECOMES THE FIRST ONE )
                      NewList.add(ActualData.get(4));
                      NewList.add(ActualData.get(0));
                      NewList.add(ActualData.get(1));
                      NewList.add(ActualData.get(2));
                      NewList.add(ActualData.get(3));

                      // CLEAR DATA FROM CURRENT CHART
                      pieChart.getData().clear();

                      // ENTER NEW DATA TO CHART
                      for(int i = 0;i<NewList.size();i++) 
                      {

                          PieChart.Data slice = new PieChart.Data(NewList.get(i).getName(),NewList.get(i).getPieValue());
                          pieChart.getData().add(slice);

                      }



                }
            });



       }


       public void EnterValues(PieChart chart) {


           PieChart.Data slice1 = new PieChart.Data("USA", 30);
           PieChart.Data slice2 = new PieChart.Data("EU", 20);
           PieChart.Data slice3 = new PieChart.Data("China", 100);
           PieChart.Data slice4 = new PieChart.Data("Japan", 50);
           PieChart.Data slice5 = new PieChart.Data("Others", 10);

           chart.getData().add(slice1);
           chart.getData().add(slice2);
           chart.getData().add(slice3);
           chart.getData().add(slice4);
           chart.getData().add(slice5);

       }


       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Application.launch(args);
       }
}
```

Comment: Does `Collections.rotate(pieChart.getData(), 1);` work?

Comment: OK, it doesn't, because the brain-dead chart API includes the nodes in the data, so you end up with a "duplicate children added" exception.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you should just be able to [`rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,int)) the pie chart data. However, because the chart API has the `Node` that represents the data as a part of the data class (which represents a major design flaw in my opinion, and renders the Chart API as not suitable for production code), this results in a "duplicate children added" error.

So it seems the only way around this is to create a deep copy of the data, and rotate that list, which is essentially what you do. Note there's no real need to create an `ObservableList` for the data copy; a plain old `List` (which has less overhead) will do. So your code can be reduced a little:

```
       button.setOnAction(e -> {

            List<Data> dataCopy = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Data d : pieChart.getData())
                dataCopy.add(new Data(d.getName(), d.getPieValue()));
            Collections.rotate(dataCopy, 1);
            pieChart.getData().setAll(dataCopy);

        });
```